# CopyWebpackPlugin fails at "run" "webpack-dev-server"

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) To copy files from my app/images directory into `public/img` at `npm run development`. But for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "webpack-dev-server"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! global-gamesey@1.0.0 webpack-dev-server: `NODE_ENV=development PORT=8080 webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --hot --inline --devtool inline-source-map --history-api-fallback`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the global-gamesey@1.0.0 webpack-dev-server script 'NODE_ENV=development PORT=8080 webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --hot --inline --devtool inline-source-map --history-api-fallback'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the global-gamesey package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     NODE_ENV=development PORT=8080 webpack-dev-server --content-base public/ --hot --inline --devtool inline-source-map --history-api-fallback
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs global-gamesey
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls global-gamesey
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/travis.tb/git/global-gamesey/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! global-gamesey@1.0.0 development: `cp views/index.html public/index.html && NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the global-gamesey@1.0.0 development script 'cp views/index.html public/index.html && NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run webpack-dev-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the global-gamesey package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cp views/index.html public/index.html && NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run webpack-dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs global-gamesey
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls global-gamesey
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/travis.tb/git/global-gamesey/npm-debug.log
```

Why is my script failing? In my webpack.config file I have included the following lines:

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack')
//copy files
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  var loaders = ['react-hot','babel']
} else {
  var loaders = ['babel']
}
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './app-client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: loaders,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    { 
     test: /\.scss$/, 
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"] 
    }
  ]},
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET)
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: '/images/', to: '/public/img/' }
    ])
 ]
};
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am coming from a Gulp perspective so am finding the way webpack deals with this simple task really odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) documentation states that you have to add the following entry to your "webpack.config.js" configuration file.

`

```
...
devServer: {
    // This is required for webpack-dev-server. The path should  
    // be an absolute path to your build destination. 
    outputPath: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
},
...`
```